# Format axis number to thousands with a comma if number>=10,000

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot Spearman correlation plots between two set of measurements in Python.
My problem is that I would like both axes to show thousands with a comma BUT ONLY if they have 5 or more digits (e.g. 1000 should be 1000, but 10000 should be 10,000).
I am sorry but I cannot post neither the data nor the plot since it is scientific material.

This is the piece of code I have tried:

```
a.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))
a.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))
```

But it obviously works with all the numbers.

Comment: `lambda x, _: f'{x:.0f}' if abs(x < 9999.5) else f'{x:,.0f}'`

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this:

```py
a.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: '{:,}'.format(x)))
```

As the `format` is the method of the string